# How to make script run in the background

Tags: php

I have seen some websites that let you submit a file, then they say "Please check back in 20 minutes and your file will be processed". So the user sends a request to the server, then the server processes it in the background.

How is this done? Specifically, how is this done in PHP?

Comment: Every PHP script "runs in background"; result of that you can find later (in subsequent requests) by a whole myriad of techniques, i.e. session-cookies...

Comment: then there's server traffic load, queuing, creation of a whole bunch of stuff etc etc. topic's too broad and off-topic.

Comment: What you mean is a scheduled task which usually is a cron job i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by calling a service working independently. For example you can do something like this:

- send a request to the service to start processing something (service return an ID of started process)
- after some time you ask service again about process status (you need to send an ID of the process)
- if service still working then you get an information about it
- if service has finish then you can get a result from it